# How can the Win32 function ExpandEnvironmentStrings fail with a zero return value?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, environment-variables, getlasterror

The docs for [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

However, I have not been able to produce a test case where the function would return zero.

```
DWORD WINAPI ExpandEnvironmentStrings(
  _In_       LPCTSTR lpSrc,
  _Out_opt_  LPTSTR lpDst,
  _In_       DWORD nSize
);
```

If either of the pointers is NULL, it just crashes and the size parameter isn't able to produce any error (if it's to small, the function returns the required size).

So is there any known case under which this function would return zero and do a SetLastError?

Comment: That's not how error reporting works in Windows, there are no "exception specifications".  Simulating an error return to test if your code is resilient to failure is of course trivial, just force the return value and error.

Comment: @HansPassant: I know that the MS docs often leave the possible errors unspecified. I was just wondering whether this function can fail at all, that is, if anyone knows of an error scenario where it would return zero.

Comment: @MartinBa any possibly situations are subject to change as they are undocumented. Normally the "something went wrong" is a panic get out for something it can't handle for which there are infinite possibilities (not all as likely).